# Cross sub domain loading of scripts is not cached

Tags: javascript, caching, asp-classic, iis-7, cross-domain

We have subDomainA.domainX.com and subDomainB.domainX.com in our intranet.

We are using a classic ASP page "pageP" in "subDomainA" to display part of a page.
"pageP" loads scripts "script1" which is 0.5 MB in size.
In subDomainA after the first loading of the script this is cached.

However when subDomainB loads pageP using CORS "script1" is always loaded with cache false. We can see this in the Network tab because the "_=timestamp" is added.

The web.config where the "pageP" is hosted has the following settings:

```
<httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
```

...

```
 <caching enabled="true">
            <profiles>
                <remove extension="*" />
                <add extension=".js" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="DontCache" location="Any" />
                <add extension=".css" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="DontCache" location="Any" />
                <add extension=".png" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="DontCache" location="Any" />
                <add extension=".jpg" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="DontCache" location="Any" />
                <add extension=".gif" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="DontCache" location="Any" />
            </profiles>
        </caching>
```

How do we ensure that "script1" when loaded from subDomainB has cache set as true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing to do with your server setup, its jQuery in client that appends that key & value.

Tell it if you want caching:

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache: true});
```

Comment: We tried ajaxSetup before the CORS request is made from subDomainB but it did not work. Where exactly has this ajaxSetup to be made?

Comment: We added it in the jQuery document ready before the CORS request on subDomainB and it worked